# Why does ranges::sort return an iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, std, c++20, range-v3

I can see that `std::sort` returns `void`. But now that `ranges` have been added to the C++20 Standard, why does `std::ranges::sort` return an `iterator`? *cppreference* specifies:

> **Return value**
>
> An iterator equal to last.

1. What's the rational behind that choice?
2. What's the use case advantage compared to `void`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to pass an end iterator to the algorithms in `std::ranges`. You can pass a sentinel instead, which is something comparable to an iterator, but it's not itself an iterator (it can't be dereferenced or incremented). Think of how this might be useful if you wanted to pass a null-terminated string to an algorithm.

`std::ranges::sort` necessarily find the end of the sequence while doing it sorting. That's useful information, so it is returned.

Comment: I am confused. The reason why `ranges::sort` returns an `end` iterator is because this was not known before the execution? The `ranges` user didn't seem to need it in the first place though. I am probably wrong, but it seems like we are neutralizing the very purpose of ranges, namely "_not having to provide the `end` iter specifically_".

Comment: I would have say, for chaining... but returning (initial) range would seems more natural then...

Comment: The end of a delimited range can be found in O(N), so yes technically it not _needed_. But by returning the position of the end, which `sort` must necessarily compute as a side-effect of sorting, it gives the user access to the end position in O(1).